# Number of partitions of list

Tags: permutations

If I have `my_list = [0, 1, 2]`. I want to figure out how many possible list partitions there are for a list of length $n$. For the above example, there would be:

```
[[0, 1, 2]]
[[0, 1], [2]]
[[0], [1, 2]]
[[0], [1], [2]]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by permutations here.   In math permutations can mean a number of different ideas and it is not exactly clear which one you mean.

Comment: Do you just mean all the ways to partshon  the list into sub lists?

Comment: Essentially, yes

Comment: Sorry, I mean a general method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list has length $n$, there are $n-1$ places to put a divider between elements.  Each choice of a set of dividers makes a different partition.  As each divider can be there or not, there are $2^{n-1}$ ways to partition the list.  In your example $n=3$ and $2^{3-1}=4$, which is the number of partitions you have found.